# React-Native Cannot read property 'bind' of undefined

Tags: reactjs, react-native, native

Two Problem, if i bind my function like this :

```
deleteTag = (id) => {
  console.log(id);
  id = 0;
  tabTag.splice(id, 1);
  --tabSize;
}

  componentTag() {
   return tabTag.map(function(item, id){
      return(
        <View key={id} style={styles.componentView}>
          <Icon name="ios-reorder"></Icon>
          <Text>{item.name}</Text> 
          <Slider style={styles.sliderBar} maximumValue={3} step={1} />
          <TouchableHighlight onPress={() => this.deleteTag.bind(this)}>
            <Icon name="close-circle"/>
          </TouchableHighlight>
        </View>
      );
    });
  }
```

My error is ' Cannot read property 'bind' of undefined '

Else

if I bind my function in constructor nothing happen

```
 constructor(props) {
     this.deleteTag = this.deleteTag.bind(this);
  }

deleteTag = (id) => {
  console.log(id);
  id = 0;
  tabTag.splice(id, 1);
  --tabSize;
}

  componentTag() {
   return tabTag.map(function(item, id){
      return(
        <View key={id} style={styles.componentView}>
          <Icon name="ios-reorder"></Icon>
          <Text>{item.name}</Text> 
          <Slider style={styles.sliderBar} maximumValue={3} step={1} />
          <TouchableHighlight onPress={this.deleteTag}>
            <Icon name="close-circle"/>
          </TouchableHighlight>
        </View>
      );
    });
  }
```

SomeOne can help me ? thanks !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because you forgot to bind `this` with map callback function, and `this` inside callback function is not referring to react class context, Here:

`tabTag.map(function(item, id){ .... })`

Use [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions):

```
tabTag.map((item, id) => { .... })
```

Now write the body with either your 1st or 2nd approach, both will work.